# apirtc, Receive calls in the background or minimized the app

Tags: call, videocall

How to receive calls when the app is in background or quit state?
They are two different states of the app, background and completely closed.

or because example:
"How to receive calls with apiRTC as does WhatsApp?"
I am implementing ApiRTC JS SDK

Comment: I can't understand what you are asking, please edit your question. This, as of now, looks like spam to me.

Comment: I have edited the question, to formulate it in a different way, tell me if it is better understood!

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. [This](https://github.com/apizee/ApiRTC-examples) is the link to some ApiRTC use case example. Your question, as is, does not have enough code to be answered. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Asking question on SO should be your last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Hi ApiRTCSupport and HardcoreGamer I am one of the developers in charge of the integration process of APIRTC with the application that ian mentions, actually we already communicated directly with APIRTC support and they mentioned that we should ask the respective question here.

the overall picture is as follows:

- We have the application fully functional and integrated with the API/SDK JS.
- The application is developed in Ionic with Cordova

> ```
> Ionic@v4  
> CordovaCLI@10, 
> cordova-android@10.1.1
> cordova-ios@6.2.0
> ```

- The minimum necessary plugins were installed (including cordova-iosrtc)
- Now the integrated p2p calls and p2p video calls are fully functional and without problems.

Now, among the new requirements are:

- The possibility of receiving incoming calls and video calls when the app is in background (minimize state), what happens is that when the app is minimized the websocket together with the execution of the JS code is completely interrupted, so for another user who wants to call the one who put the minimized app says "user is offline", we need the guide on how to handle this first use case.
- Second requirement the possibility to receive calls and video calls when the app is in quit state (app killed) [ like Telegram, WhatsApp, Messenger, etc], so it should be able to receive the notification and allow to execute the JS code that would allow the connection with the apiRTC services/servers. in this case we have already investigated about VoIP(for iOS) and push notifications with high Priority(for Android), but we wanted to know if this is the way to go or you have a different implementation for ApiRTC services.

Thank you and really sorry for the little information provided at the beginning.

If you need any more specific information I will be waiting for your answers.